# Shell buffer echoes partial long lines

Tags: comint, shell-mode

I've written a command that ssh-es to a remote host and runs an interactive command there.  Something like:

```
(defun remote-command ()
  (interactive)
  (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*remote-command*"))
  (async-shell-command "ssh remote-host interactive-command" (current-buffer)))
```

A longstanding annoyance has been that when I enter a very long line, some portion of the end of the line is echoed back before the command line is executed by `interactive-command`.  The main notable consequence, aside from screen clutter, is that if the end of the line contains an odd number of quotation marks, `electric-pair-mode` gets confused and no longer inserts matching pairs when I type a quote.

When I try running this ssh command from an OS X Terminal, I see similar behavior, except that the echoed portion is everything but the first physical line that the terminal presents.  I discovered by accident that if I give ssh the `-t` option in Terminal, the echoing stops completely.  I tried adding that option to my Emacs command, but it makes no difference.

That's that I've tried that have made no difference:

- `stty -echo` before running `interactive-command`
- Setting the `TERM` environment variable to various settings before running `interactive-command`, eg: `vt100`, `dumb`
- Setting `comint-process-echoes` to `t`

If it makes a difference, `interactive-command` is actually `spark-shell`.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like I mentioned, the command I was running was actually `spark-shell`.  I finally discovered that this command can be run with the option `-Xnojline`, and boom, none of my lines are echoed any longer, partially or fully.